# What is the equivalent of WinForm's DataGridView in Android Xamarin?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, xamarin.android, android-gridview

In my C# WinForms project I have a `DataGridView` on my form which I fill with data through assigning my list of objects (e.g. `Line`) to its `DataSource`.

```
List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
//lines is filled with data...
dataGridView1.DataSource = lines;
```

I also made a Android project in the same solution and both projects retrieve the same data through a third "core" project.

The problem is; how do I create and fill a grid like object for Android? I know there's a `GridView` as well, but I'm not sure how I should fill this with my object instead of the images that are used in the [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/layout/grid_view/create_a_grid_view/).